# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - Parsing php'd data

Tags: php, html

I have a php file called items.php which has table with tr and td. The contents of the table are dynamically created like this:

```
<table>
 <tr><td>Item Name</td><td>Price</td></tr>

<?php
$sqlquery="select * from items_data";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sqlquery);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?> <tr><td><span><?php echo $row['item_name'];?></td></span><td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="<?php echo $row['item_name'];?>" <?php echo ($row['availability']=='Yes' ? "checked":"");?>/></td></tr>
<?php       }
}
?>
```

Now I use a Simple HTML DOM Parser.

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html('items.php');
$rows = $html->find('td');
foreach($rows as $row) {
   echo $row->plaintext;
}
?>
```

The result of this is the static data which is the first row of the table:
Item_name and Item_Price. 
The Php data isnt getting parsed.

My question is, How to parse the php data from html file ?

Comment: Are you seeing the static php in there? Something like `<?php echo 'test'; ?>` instead of 'test' (What you're looking for?)

Comment: Item Name Price  <-- this is the output I am getting.(column names which are already predefined) what i am looking for is the data that the php will produce and store in the <td> tag